# How to override a method in a Typescript class which uses generics

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Is it possible to override a method on a Typescript class and define different parameter types using generics? I want to do this to create a flexible abstract base class, but then benefit by strict typing on the child class.

I suspect this could be another example of the ["correlated union types" issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) but in this case I wonder since by using interfaces, surely TypeScript *does* know enough information not to produce an error.

The below code produces the following error in TypeScript `v4.6.3` against the `doSomething` override in class `B`:

```
TS2416: Property 'doSomething' in type 'B' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'A'.   
Type '(opts: BOpts) => void' is not assignable to type '<T extends AOpts>(opts: T) => void'.     
Types of parameters 'opts' and 'opts' are incompatible.       
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'BOpts'.         
Property 'bar' is missing in type 'AOpts' but required in type 'BOpts'.
```

```js
interface AOpts {
    foo: number;
}

class A {
    public doSomething<T extends AOpts>(opts: T) {
        console.log(opts.foo);
    }
}

interface BOpts extends AOpts {
    bar: number;
}

class B extends A {
    // this line errors
    public override doSomething(opts: BOpts) {
        super.doSomething(opts);
        console.log(opts.bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is not type safe as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w8EZEN).  If you don't plan to upcast `B` to `A` and want the compiler to accept this, you can take advantage of method parameter bivariance and write it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/NlEbem) without generics.  It has the same type safety hole but the compiler accepts it.  Does that fully address your question?  If so I can write up an answer explaining and linking to docs.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for the example, I hadn't considered that :)

Your suggestion makes sense and totally works for me, thanks! Yes I have no plans to upcast to `A` - though I can see there is type safety hole I don't love.

For reasons I won't go into, the codebase I'm working on actually has a Class hierarchy 3 deep. I was attempting to skip the override in the middle class as the code did nothing, but I see now it's necessary for the TS compiler. It's a little unwieldy, but the code I really have is closer to [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJyLDm) - your solution applies to this too :)